# LUA: Find and return string in double quotes

Tags: string, lua, find

I try to find a string in a HTML-Body, the string looks like `var version="1,1,0,0";` and i only want to extract the content between the double quotes. I have tried it with

`local version = string.match(response.body, ".version.")
 return version`

Comment: `local version = response.body:match('var%s+version=(%b"");'):sub(2,-2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `var%s+version="([^"]+)` pattern with `string.match` that will only output the captured text (i.e. the one matched with `([^"]+)`) (see this [Lua patterns tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial)):

```
s = [[var version="1,1,0,0";]]
res = string.match(s, [[var%s+version="([^"]+)]])
print(res)
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/mEaC0E).

**Details**:

- `var`  - a literal `var` text
- `%s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `version="` - literal `version="` text
- `([^"]+)` - a capturing group matching 1+ chars other than `"`.

If you want to specify that there can only be digits and commas inside `version="..."`, use `var%s+version="([%d,]+)` pattern (see [demo](https://ideone.com/DlARMQ)) where `[%d,]+` matches 1+ digits or commas.

Answer (score 1):

```
--> parsing first single quoted string only.
str1 = [[var version='1,1,0,0';]]
res1 = string.match(str1, "%b''")
res1 = string.gsub(res1, "'", '')
print(res1)

--> parsing first double quoted string only.
str2 = [[var version="1,1,0,0";]]
res2 = string.match(str2, '%b""')
res2 = string.gsub(res2, '"', "")
print(res2)


--> parsing all single quoted strings.
line1 = "major_ver='1', minor_ver='1.1'"
for chunk in string.gmatch(line1, "'(.-)'") do print(chunk) end

--> parsing all double quoted strings.
line2 = 'major_ver="2", minor_ver="2.2"'
for chunk in string.gmatch(line2, '"(.-)"') do print(chunk) end

line3 = [[major_ver="3", minor_ver="3.3"]]
for chunk in string.gmatch(line3, [["(.-)"]]) do print(chunk) end
```

Click on [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/wZWe4g) for live result.